# Regular expression for string end with number

Tags: c++, regex

1. I need to use std::regex and validate the input strings in C++
   Input strings should be between `folder-1` or `folder-01` or `folder-001` to `folder-200` (Prefix must be 'folder-')
   How to write a regular expression for this?
2. Is the regular expressions uses in C++ different from regular expressions use in other languages such as PHP and JavaScript?
3. Do most C++ developers use 'Boost regx' or 'std::regex' (some comments please)?

Comment: `folder-\d{3}` if it's exactly 3 digits, `folder-\d+` if it's as many digits.

Comment: @Rapptz - I need to accept 'one digit', 'tow digit' and 'three digit' only

Comment: Hi expert, I need one more help related to this question. This regular expression  `folder-\\d{1,3}` support my requirement. but If I need to avoid the numbers start from zero,ex: `folder-0` `folder-01`, `folder-071`. Instead of that I need only allow  `folder-1`, `folder-71` `folder-171` (simple postfix number should not start with zero). So what should be the regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
const std::regex re("folder-\\d{1,3}");
```

example:

http://liveworkspace.org/code/1EfD0Q$12

You can read about std::regex in C++ standard, or about boost::regex in boost docs.
boost::regex is stable library and std::regex is new feature of C++11 standard.

Now, for example gcc 4.7 cannot handle this regex, so, use boost is better (in sample on LWS I use boost::regex instead of std::regex, since std::regex in gcc 4.7 cannot handle correctly {n, m}).

Comment: I marked this as the answer, pleas kindly correct the sample at liveworkspace for others use. thank you.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya sample on LWS cannot be corrected, since this correct regular expression not work, since this syntax {n,m} is not implemented in std yet. Anyway, edited for boost instead of std.

Answer (score 2):

Try using,

```
  System.out.println("folder-004".matches("^folder-\\d{1,3}?$"));
```

for more details http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html